# Getting oauth_token_secret DotNetOpenAuth

Tags: oauth, dotnetopenauth

i am using the dotnetopenauth library to connection and authorize my users with linkedin.

Is there anyway to get the oauth_token_secret from the dnoa library after my user has been authenticated/authorized?

I need the oauth_token_secret for signing my requests after i have the access token, and am performing that part myself using the oAuthBase.cs from the oauth site.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just seen the ITokenManager interface.

FYI its here: [interface](https://github.com/AArnott/dotnetopenid/blob/master/src/DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth/OAuth/ChannelElements/ITokenManager.cs)

Need to implement that in order to save to a persistent store.